# Is using memcpy() in this way bad practice?

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

I'm messing around with arrays and attempting to find efficient ways of performing operations on the data.

Adding values at the end is easy enough but shifting the data on or more indexes back has drawbacks. I could potentially create an new array with sufficient space and copy the data starting at the shifted index and then delete the original and swap the pointers but I believe this method is memory inefficient.

I ended up stumbling upon utilizing memcpy() on the array itself assuming there's space in it for the shift and it worked beautifully, however I am concerned that it's not proper or if I'm doing the same thing only that not consciously.

My code looks like this

```
const int size = 25, buffer = 25;

int num[size+buffer]{}; 
initialize(num, size);


cout << "Values:" << endl;
print(num, size+buffer);
cout << endl << endl;

memcpy( &(num[size]), num, sizeof(int) * size );

cout << "Values:" << endl;
print(num, size + buffer);
cout << endl << endl;
```

initialize is a function to assign values from a file and its a simple for loop;
By the second print function the array holds two copies of the values. If everything works as I think it is I'm thinking of shifting it the amount needed for the new values and then inserting them there. Seems clean and quick and hopefully memory efficient.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about what the code you show/don't show is supposed to do. However, be aware that `memcpy` gives **undefined behaviour** if the source and destination overlap. However, the somewhat similar `memmove` is defined for overlapping buffers.

Comment: Also,  it'll only work for trivially copyable types.

Comment: Use `std::vector` for variable-sized arrays and `std::array` for fixed-sized arrays. Prefer `std::copy` over `memcpy`.

Comment: I see, I'll look into memMove, I appreciate  the insight.

Comment: memcpy in C++ code much more often turns out to be a completely broken behavior, than not. You can never go wrong by using `std::copy`, and it will simply devolve into `memcpy` whenever it's safe to do so.

Comment: I know about std::vector and array but I was making my own. It's a hobby project so I enjoy going through the process

Comment: From [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):  "_When copying overlapping ranges, `std::copy` is appropriate when copying to the left (beginning of the destination range is outside the source range) while `std::copy_backward` is appropriate when copying to the right (end of the destination range is outside the source range)_"

Comment: Oh, wow, this is fantastic information. Thank you

Comment: I looked into std::copy and it seems to do a simple iteration through the array and swap elements. This is the behavior I was attmepting to avoid. Is this similar to ho memcopy works?

Comment: Yes, that is similar to how memcpy works.  Iterates over and copies.

Comment: @Pichuu64 `std::copy` behaves _as if_ it iterated over the source range and coped each element to the destination range.  In all implementations I'm aware of though, it will delegate to `memcpy` when it's safe to do so.

Comment: If you want to be able to efficiently insert and shift elements, then you may want to consider using a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) instead of an array. In C++, you can use `std::list` for this. However, a linked list also has disadvantages, for example an array allows for fast random access whereas a linked list does not. If you want to combine the best of both worlds and minimize the disadvantages, you can use [self-balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), which are implemented by `std::set` in C++.

Comment: One big upside with the `std::copy` family of functions is that you'll probably get a `memcpy` or `memmove` for trivially copyable types - or a regular loop for types that are not trivially copyable. Check the optimized assembly code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, the disadvantages are the reason I have avoided utilizing linked list in my program. that and how quickly bloated they become.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the self balancing binary tree sounds enticing. I hadn't hear about them before. I'll research ti, thank you

Comment: @Pichuu64: There are also many other types of data structures which may suit your needs better. For example [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which are implemented in C++ with `std::unordered_set`. You may also want to take a look at `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, as this allows you to store key/value pairs. In any case, it seems that an array is not the ideal data structure for what you are doing, if you need to do efficient insertions. Copying an array on every insert operation is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably implement it more efficiently by using a std::deque which is optimised to allow insertion and removal of items at the beginning and end.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Although we could disappear down a bolt-hole in terms of algorithms etc, the nub of your question is, ***"is this considered bad practice"***.  The answer to that is clearly "yes"; the modern philosophy is to write "expressive code".  If you think that expressive code may be inefficient, and that working "close to the metal is best", check out Matt Godbolt's talk at CppCon 2017 in terms of how much optimisation compilers do for you.  The message is clear; don't write "clever optimised code", just be clear and expressive about intent with the source, and let the compiler do the optimisation for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4

Another thing to consider is that a lot of algorithms are ranked according to `Big O Notation`, which implies that some inefficient algorithms should never be used.  However, some of the so-called inefficient algorithms are better in terms of `locality of reference`; particularly if you're using small amounts of data that fits within a cache line.  Linked lists will most likely jump around memory, leading to cache misses.  Check out this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs

As suggested in the comments, also check out the following video about data structures (this link skips the first 8 minutes, because they are unimportant):
https://youtu.be/4IrUAqYKjIA?t=525

Comment: Yes, a deque allows efficient insertions at the start and end, but it has the same problem as an array when it comes to inserting elements in the middle.

Comment: Although I also find your link to Matt Godbolt's presentation highly interesting, it is not related to data structures, but rather to general compiler optimizations. Therefore, I don't think it is appropriate to mention it in your answer. In my opinion, the best video I have encountered on data structures is [this video from CS50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IrUAqYKjIA) (the first 6 minutes of the video should be skipped, because it is only a recap of a previous lesson).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel 1) It may be the case that he's just doing simple insertions for which a std::deque would be a good fit; indeed if he's randomly accessing entities then you'd be getting into linked lists etc, or for small amounts of data a vector would suffice.

2) The GodBolt video is appropriate on a more philosophical level.  I used to hand-optimise C code with blocks of assembler, but these days there's little point to doing so.  I find that GodBolt's video really makes a good case for leaving optimisation up to the compiler and writing code in an expressive fashion for readability's sake

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks for the video link, added to the answer.

Comment: Just as a warning: The video on data structures uses the language C, not C++. I think this is best, because C++ implements most data structures for you, so you must use C if you want to understand how the data structures really work under the hood. However, some people may consider it inappropriate to post a link to something in the language C in an answer to a C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to just use `std::vector`. If it is storing a POD (plain old data) type it will optimize to use `memmove`. (Note: [Using `memcpy` as you are doing is not allowed on overlapping data. Things will break. When you least expect them](https://lwn.net/Articles/414467/).) And if it is storing a more complex type, it will do all of the proper extensions, copies, moves or swaps.